# Как занести данные с массива в таблицу?

Tags: html, javascript

Есть у меня два массива и таблица, нужно все эти данные занести в таблицу, 
следующим образом.

Все единицы в одну ячейку, двойки во вторую, тройки в следующую и так далее.

```
mas = new Array(day, month, year); //10,07,2014
mas2 = new Array(32, 16, 7, 5);

<table class="table_block" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td id="1">11</td>
            <td id="4">нет</td>
            <td id="7">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="2">22</td>
            <td id="5">5</td>
            <td id="8">8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="3">3</td>
            <td id="7">7</td>
            <td id="9">99</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить [такое решение](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/96bVc/2/).

```
var mas = [10, 07, 2014],
    mas2 = [32, 16, 7, 5],
    arr = mas.concat(mas2).join('').split(''),
    group,
    tbl = '<table class="table_block"><tr>';

function getSameDig(a, v) {
    var digits = '', i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(+a[i] === v) digits += a[i];
    }
    return digits;
}
for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    group = getSameDig(arr, i);
    tbl += '<td id="' + i + '">' + (group ? group : 'нет') + '</td>';
    if(i % 3 === 0 && i < 9) tbl += '</tr><tr>';
}
tbl += '</tr></table>';
document.body.innerHTML = tbl;
```

Comment: @Deonis,нужно чтобы оно заполняло по вертикали, а не по горизонтали, например
делает ваш код 
111 22 3
4 5 6
77 нет нет 

а нужно 

111 4 77
22 5 нет
3 6 нет

Comment: @Surfer, цикл измените:

    // ...
    for(var i = 1, k = 1; k <= 9; i+=3, k++){
        group = getSameDig(arr, i);
        tbl += '<td id="' + i + '">' + (group ? group : 'нет') + '</td>';
        if(k % 3 === 0 && k < 9){
            i = (k / 3) - 2;
            tbl += '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }
    // ...

Comment: Посчитать можно [вот так][1]. Вам выводить не нужно, значит просто добавляйте значения в массив или объект, как в моём примере. Ключ - это цифра, а значение - количество таких цифр.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/96bVc/4/

Comment: @Deonis, как добавить классы для каждой ячейки, например для каждой ячейки свой ​​"background" а для ячеек в которых не имеется данных добавлять "background:red"

Comment: @Surfer, а чуть-чуть свои усилия приложить слабо? Для решения последней задачи, у вас уже всё есть, нужно только самую малость поднапрячься.

Comment: @Surfer и что именно непонятно ? как сделать условие "есть-нет данные" ? так это условие уже есть.

Comment: @Surfer а вы программист ?

Comment: @Deonis, пожалуйста скажите как ??

Comment: @Surfer, [смотрите тут][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/96bVc/5/